# Using Spring data jpa auditing to log into tables other than the entity’s table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

In Hibernate Envers it is possible to have a separate audit table. Similarly, is it possible to log into tables other than the entity’s table using Spring Data JPA auditing?

Comment: It's clear exactly what you're asking.  Envers places all audit history in separate tables from the base entity table, so that's by default.  I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe this can be of use: https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-envers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [auditing feature of Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing) just fills attributes in the entity you are persisting. How and where these attributes get persisted is controlled by you JPA implementation and of course your database.

JPA offers [`@SecondaryTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html) to map fields to a second table.

If this isn't flexible enough for you, you can always employ database tools to achieve the effect by mapping the entity to a view which via triggers distributes the data however you want.